# Geometry "Acute and Obtuse Polygons" Inscribed in Circle

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I am trying to inscribe polygons inside circles, given ONLY the lengths of the sides of the triangles. I have derived the angle, $\theta$, from the law of cosines, where $a$ and $b$ both equal the radius of the circle, and $c=d$ is the length of one side of the $n$-sided polygon:
$$θ_d=arccos(1−\frac{d^2}{2r^2})$$
In the case of the "acute" polygon, a root finder for:
$$\sum_{i=1}^narccos(1−\frac{{d_i}^2}{2r^2})=2\pi$$
is all that is needed to determine the radius, and then individual $\theta$'s.

However, if the polygon is "obtuse", the angle of the greatest length side will be $θ_d=2\pi-arccos(1−\frac{d^2}{2r^2})$, which represents the "other" solution to the inverse cosine (e.g. $arccos(.5)=\pm\frac{2\pi}3$).

It is important that I use the right equation prior to using a root-finder, as using the wrong equation causes undesired results in my calculations.

**Is there a way to algebraicly determine whether the polygon fits the "obtuse" or "acute" categories using the lengths of the sides *before* running a program to calculate the radius?**

Here is a picture of examples of my definition of acute and obtuse inscribed polygons.
[image]

Comment: Is this for use in a computer programming application? If so, you could check if the center of your circle is contained in your polygon using something like Point-in-Polygon (the center being inside the polygon translates to the acute case, and it being outside translates to the obtuse case). If it's not, then let me know and I'll try and think of something else to help you.

Comment: @KReiser The question asks how to determine the "type" *before* calculating the radius. The center of the circumcircle is not known at that point.

Comment: It is for computer programming, but I need to calculate the radius and then the vertices of the polygon, so I cannot create a polygon, and then determine if it is acute or obtuse, as errors will arise. Though, I'll look if I can implement the point-in-polygon idea... may not work. I'll see.

Comment: @dxiv: good catch- my mistake.

Comment: @LoganHodgson The limit case between *acute* and *obtuse* appears to be when the largest side is a diameter of the circumcircle.Maybe you could run a quick check to see if the other segments can fit *inside* a half-circle drawn on the largest side. That's just an idea, not a proof of course.

Comment: Do you have an idea on how to do that?

Comment: @LoganHodgson Let $d_1=2 r_1$ be the largest side, check if $\sum_{i=2}^n \arccos(1−\frac{{d_i}^2}{2r_1^2}) \le \pi$.

Comment: Ah, so kind of check type of polygon while calculating the radius... neat idea!